# Google cloud console [GCP] not working properly with k8s

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I have a problem with Google cloud console and kubernates

i have two projects:

```
$ gcloud projects list
PROJECT_ID      NAME           PROJECT_NUMBER
telemetry       Telemetry      571056202575
opex-prod       OPEX           992345650242
```

If I check current project:

```
$ gcloud config get-value project
Your active configuration is: [cloudshell-20766]
telemetry
```

and list of my namespaces (i will show only my namespace, not default and kube* ones):

```
$ kubectl get namespace
NAME              STATUS   AGE
development       Active   3d18h
```

so, now if I want change project (which has different pods and namespaces):

```
$ gcloud config set project opex-prod
Updated property [core/project].
$ gcloud config get-value project
Your active configuration is: [cloudshell-20766]
opex-prod
```

but if i check the namespaces on opex-prox project i will have namespace of my other project

```
$ kubectl get namespace
NAME              STATUS   AGE
development       Active   3d18h
```

in `opex-prod` I don't have `development` but `prod-a`

If i change projects and namespaces in Google Cloud dashboard I can see correct namespaces

what i'm missing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kubectl commands don't work based on gcloud project config. They work based on kubeconfig set in your local environment. To set kubeconfig to point to a particular project's cluster, run `gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-name` command after you change your gcloud project config. Read [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl) for more info.

Comment: uuuuhuuuu...it works! I also had to specify the zone ( with --zone)